# Proof by induction with a set

Tags: induction

I need to prove I formula by induction, but I don't know how to do it.

The problem is :

Given a set S, prove by induction

```
∀X·X∈F(S)⇒(∀Y ·Y ∈F(S)⇒card(X×Y)=card(X)∗card(Y))
```

How should I start?

Comment: what is $F(S)$?

Comment: It is for Finite(S)

Comment: finite subsets of $S$?

Comment: Yes, at least that is what I understand

Comment: what is your definition of card?

Comment: it returns the cardinality of the set

Comment: It sounds like you are simply trying to prove the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  All this talk about $F(S)$ and such is muddying the statement.  A more compact statement is "Given two finite sets $X$ and $Y$ one has $|X\times Y|=|X|\times|Y|$."  To prove this, I suggest running double-induction, the outer loop on the number of elements in $X$ and the inner loop on the number of elements in $Y$.  To make matters easier, you could assume without loss of generality that $X=\{1,2,3,4,\dots,x\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,\dots,y\}$.  To fully generalize, use bijections.

Comment: One of the key observations to make here, is that $\{1,2,\dots,x\}\times\{1,2,\dots,y,y+1\} = \left(\{1,2,\dots,x\}\times\{1,2,\dots,y\}\right)\cup\left(\{1,2,\dots,x\}\times \{y+1\}\right)$, at which point we can use the [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) (*or a short proof for that as well*) along with our induction hypothesis and a bit of middle-school algebra to get what we wanted.